# How to split Large files in Apache Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a requirement to split millions of data(csv format) to single raw in apache nifi.Currently I am using multiple split text processor to achieve this. Is there any other way to do this instead of multiple split text processor

Comment: Why are you using multiple `SplitText` , processor can be configured to produce one flowfile per record in CSV by setting `Line Split Count = 1`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SplitRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.SplitRecord/index.html) Processor.
You need to create a *Record Reader* and *Record Writer* Service first.
Then you can give a value for *Records Per Split* to split at n position.